# How to get the height of android notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I have to use custom notification layout for my app. The notification fits in the default space so don't want to use `bigContentView`. But to redistribute my layout components properly, I would like to know the height of default notification that phones creates. It looks approximately 50dp in my MarshMellow phone.

Note: I would also like to know the same for pre-lollipop phones

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's 16+16+8+14+16 = 70dp. See [design guidelines](https://material.google.com/patterns/notifications.html#notifications-content) and [dimens.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml):

```
<!-- Size of notification text (see TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent) -->
<dimen name="notification_text_size">14sp</dimen>
<!-- Size of notification text titles (see TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title) -->
<dimen name="notification_title_text_size">16sp</dimen>
<!-- Size of smaller notification text (see TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Line2, Info, Time) -->
<dimen name="notification_subtext_size">12sp</dimen>
```

Pre lollipop (or at least kitkat) dimens can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml).

Based on these values

```
<!-- Size of notification text (see TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent) -->
<dimen name="notification_text_size">14dp</dimen>
<!-- Size of notification text titles (see TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title) -->
<dimen name="notification_title_text_size">18dp</dimen>
<!-- Size of smaller notification text (see TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Line2, Info, Time) -->
<dimen name="notification_subtext_size">12dp</dimen>
```

Height for those should be 16+18+8+14+16 = 72dp. I cannot find pre lollipop specs for the padding, so I used the material ones.

Comment: @suko no, slight difference

Comment: In Android N, this is 92dp. See notification_min_height in dimens.xml:
 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml